# zombie process can't be killed

Tags: c, linux, zombie-process

Is there a way to kill a zombie process? I've tried calling `exit` to kill the process and even sending `SIGINT` signal to the process, but it seems that nothing can kill it. I'm programming for Linux.

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten to make the obvious joke: the way to kill a zombie is a shoot in the head.

Comment: [When will kill PID fail?](http://serverfault.com/questions/276557/when-will-kill-pid-fail/276558#276558)

Comment: See also [What does reaping children imply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885831)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zombie processes are already dead, so they cannot be killed, they can only be reaped, which has to be done by their parent process via `wait*()`. This is usually called the `child reaper` idiom, in the signal handler for `SIGCHLD`:

```
while (wait*(... WNOHANG ...)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I got to use `zombie`, `dead`, `killed` and `child reaper` in this answer :)

Comment: This code is incorrect. If you put that in your `SIGCHLD` handler, you risk blocking and never returning.

Comment: @R..: you're supposed to use one of the `wait()` variants that support `WNOHANG`

Comment: You can also have the parent process ignore the child status via `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)`.  The child process goes away (leaves no zombie) as soon as it exits because the parent has registered a lack of interest in the well being of its children.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script I created to kill ALL zombie processes.  It uses the GDB debugger to attach to the parent process and send a waitpid to kill the zombie process.  This will leave the parent live and only slay the zombie.

GDB debugger will need to be installed and you will need to be logged in with permissions to attach to a process. This has been tested on Centos 6.3.

```
#!/bin/bash
##################################################################
# Script: Zombie Slayer
# Author: Mitch Milner
# Date:   03/13/2013 ---> A good day to slay zombies
#
# Requirements: yum install gdb
#               permissions to attach to the parent process
#
# This script works by using a debugger to
# attach to the parent process and then issuing
# a waitpid to the dead zombie. This will not kill
# the living parent process.
##################################################################

clear
# Wait for user input to proceed, give user a chance to cancel script
echo "***********************************************************"
echo -e "This script will terminate all zombie process."
echo -e "Press [ENTER] to continue or [CTRL] + C to cancel:"
echo "***********************************************************"
read cmd_string
echo -e "\n"

# initialize variables
intcount=0
lastparentid=0

# remove old gdb command file
rm -f /tmp/zombie_slayer.txt

# create the gdb command file
echo "***********************************************************"
echo "Creating command file..."
echo "***********************************************************"
ps -e -o ppid,pid,stat,command | grep Z | sort | while read LINE; do
  intcount=$((intcount+1))
  parentid=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'`
  zombieid=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}'`
  verifyzombie=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $3}'`

  # make sure this is a zombie file and we are not getting a Z from
  # the command field of the ps -e -o ppid,pid,stat,command
  if [ "$verifyzombie" == "Z" ]
  then
    if [ "$parentid" != "$lastparentid" ]
    then
      if [ "$lastparentid" != "0" ]
      then
        echo "detach" >> /tmp/zombie_slayer.txt
      fi
    echo "attach $parentid" >> /tmp/zombie_slayer.txt
    fi
    echo "call waitpid ($zombieid,0,0)" >> /tmp/zombie_slayer.txt
    echo "Logging: Parent: $parentid  Zombie: $zombieid"
    lastparentid=$parentid
  fi
done
if [ "$lastparentid" != "0" ]
then
  echo "detach" >> /tmp/zombie_slayer.txt
fi

# Slay the zombies with gdb and the created command file
echo -e "\n\n"
echo "***********************************************************"
echo "Slaying zombie processes..."
echo "***********************************************************"
gdb -batch -x /tmp/zombie_slayer.txt
echo -e "\n\n"
echo "***********************************************************"
echo "Script complete."
echo "***********************************************************"
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Didn't run on Ubuntu 14.04: `warning: /tmp/zombie_slayer.txt: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2):

A zombie process is a process id (and associated termination status and resource usage information) that has not yet been waited for by its parent process. The only ways to eliminate it are to get its parent to wait for it (sometimes this can be achieved by sending `SIGCHLD` to the parent manually if the parent was just buggy and had a race condition where it missed the chance to wait) but usually you're out of luck unless you forcibly terminate the parent.

**Edit:** Another way, if you're desperate and don't want to kill the parent, is to attach to the parent with gdb and forcibly call `waitpid` on the zombie child.

Answer (score 1):

`kill -17 ZOMBIE_PID`

OR

`kill -SIGCHLD ZOMBIE_PID`

would possibly work, bu tlike everyone else said, it is waiting for the parent to call `wait()` so unless the parent dies without reaping, and it got stuck there for some reason you might not want to kill it.

Comment: but i think this is wrong, you might have to send that to the parent, idk

Answer (score 0):

if I recall correctly, killing the parent of a zombie process will allow the zombie process to die.

use `ps faux` to get a nice hierarchical tree of your running processes showing parent/child relationships.

Comment: It actually allows it to be reaped by `init`.

Answer (score -2):

See [unix-faqs](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-13.html) "How do I get rid of zombie processes that persevere?"

You cannot kill zombies, as they are already dead. But if you have too many zombies then kill parent process or restart service.

You can try to kill zombie process using its pid

```
kill -9 pid
```

Please note that kill -9 does not guarantee to kill a zombie process

Comment: Not only does it not guarantee to kill a zombie process. `kill -9` **can never** kill a zombie process.