# What does reaping children imply?

Tags: c, zombie-process, waitpid

I have just had a lecture that sums reaping as:

**Reaping**

- Performed by parent on terminated child (using wait or waitpid)

  Parent is given exit status informaton

  Kernel then deletes zombie child process

So I understand that reaping is done by calling `wait` or `waitpid` from the parent process after which the kernel deletes the zombie process. If this actually is the case, that reaping is done only when calling `wait` or `waitpid`, why do the child processes actually go away after returning in theor entry function - I mean that indeed does seem as if the child processes have been reaped and thus no resources are wasted even though the parent process may not be waiting.

**So is "reaping" only possible when calling `wait` or `waitpid`? Is processes are "reaped" as long as they return and exit from their entry function (which I assume all processes do) - what is the point of talking about "reaping" as if it was something special?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The child process does not *fully* "go away" when it exits.  It ceases to exist as a running process, and most/all of its resources (memory, open files, etc.) are released, *but* it still remains in the process table.  It remains in the process table because that's where its exit status is stored, so that the parent can retrieve it by calling one of the `wait` variants.  If the parent fails to call `wait`, the process table entry sticks around — and that's what makes it a "zombie".

I said that most/all of its resources are released, but the one resource that's definitely still consumed is that process table slot.

As long as the (dead) child's parent exists, the kernel doesn't know that the parent isn't going to call `wait` eventually, so the process table slot has to stay there, so that the eventual call to `wait` (if there is one) can return the proper exit status.

If the parent eventually exits (without ever calling `wait`), the child will be inherited by the grandparent, which is usually a "master" process like the shell, or `init`, that does routinely call `wait` and that will finally "reap" the poor young zombie.

So, yes, it really is true that the only way for the parent to properly "reap" the child is, just as was said in your lecture, to call one of the `wait` functions.  (Or to exit, but that's not an option if the parent is long-running.)

Footnote: I said "the child will be inherited by the grandparent", but I think I was wrong, there.  Under Unix and Linux, orphaned processes are generally always inherited by pid 1, aka `init`.

Comment: And the only way to remove it from the process table is by calling one of the wait functions in the parent process?

Comment: @npp> Yes. And eventually, if no other process deals with that, it will go all the way up to process 1, which will do it.

Comment: "orphaned processes are generally always inherited by pid 1", yes, unless an ancestor between the child and init has called prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER )

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist Thank you *very* much for that note.  I have been speculating about the need for something precisely like this `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER)`.  I didn't realize it existed already.

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of the `wait*()` call is to allow the child process to report a status back to the parent process. When the child process exits, the operating system holds that status data in a little data structure until the parent reads it. *Reaping* in that sense is cleaning out that little data structure.

If the parent does not care about waiting for status from the child, the code could be written in a way to allow the parent to ignore the status, and so the reaping occurs semi-automatically. One way is to ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal.

Another way is to perform a double-fork to create a grandchild process instead. When doing this, the "parent" does a blocking `wait()` after a call to `fork()`. Then, the child performs another `fork()` to create the grandchild and then immediately exits, causing the parent to unblock. The grandchild now does the real work, and is automatically reaped by the `init` process.