Does Java automatically reap a child process on Linux
Does a child Process created by a Java application using ProcessBuilder get reaped on exit assuming assuming the application waits for termination with waitFor ?
I am using JDK 11 on Linux.

What Happened When You Tried It?

Shouldn't this information be available without having to try it?

It is probably not documented, because I think this is an OS implementation detail. That said, waitFor likely uses the lower level wait function mentioned in the linked question (on the OSes where this is relevant), and thus the process is reaped.

Thanks. Yes it's a OS specific implementation detail, however I could not find any resources confirming one way or the other on this question. It would be good to have a authoritative answer on StackOverflow which can be useful for the community.

"Shouldn't this information be available without having to try it?" - Not if it the behavior is not specified.   And since you haven't told us what Java version and what OS platform you are using ... it is difficult to go into the implementation specific behavior.

"It would be good to have a authoritative answer on StackOverflow which can be useful for the community." - StackOverflow is not authoritative.  We are not a legitimate authority on Java matters.  The authority is Oracle & the OpenJDK team.

Added Java and OS details to the question.

Meaning of authoritative given by google able to be trusted as being accurate or true; reliable. I consider Stackoverflow  to be authoritative in this sense, not sure what is the goal of this community if not being reliable and accurate.

The Java binary is a binary just like any other program.  It follows the same rules as other programs, as described in that ‘What does reaping imply’ link.

I don't think that's the case as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885831/what-does-reaping-children-imply, which states that the parent process needs to some specific work for reaping the child process.

See https://bugs.python.org/issue1214859 and https://pypi.org/project/pyreap/ for process reaping in python

@StephenC is correct, SO is not an authoritative source: the Java documentation is. NB Wikipedia describes itself as an unreliable source too. There is nothing to prevent incorrect information from appearing in either place at any time. All there is is a process to detect it.

Here is a writeup not only showing what we know meanwhile but also with references to Java API Documentation: https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1247983/java-approach-to-zombie-processes

For Java 17 on Linux, the observed behavior is that child processes are reaped on exit, not when waitFor is called.  You can use the following simple test program to verify.
public class ProcessTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] SLEEP = new String[]{"/usr/bin/sleep", "10"};
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command(SLEEP).start();
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        System.out.println("RC is " + p.waitFor());
    }
}

Compile and run the above class in the background from a shell prompt.  While that is running, poll ps -l to watch the process status for sleep.  If there is a zombie it should be observed in the 10 seconds between "/usr/bin/sleep 10" finishing, the waitFor() call happening.  When I ran it, I couldn't see a Zombie process.
You can modify the code to try other use-cases; e.g. what happens when the child process writes to standard output.
NOTE: this is only the observed behavior.  AFAIK, it is not specified in the official Java documentation.  As such, the behavior could vary between different Java versions and different OS platforms.
(I would anticipate the behavior I observed to be consistent for all Sun/Oracle versions of Java, on all Linux and UNIX based systems including MacOS.  But that's just my guess ...)
NOTE 2: this is not an authoritative source.  On this, the only source that is truly authoritative is the OpenJDK source code.

If my methodology is questionable, please comment (politely).

"the observed behavior is that child processes are reaped on exit, not when waitFor is called." -- how on Earth can you tell that from the code you've written. You exit immediately after calling waitFor. Try sleeping another 20 seconds between calling waitFor and exiting.

Here is a counter-example: https://github.com/OoliteProject/OoliteStarter starts a process that it waitfors with a one second timeout. https://github.com/OoliteProject/OoliteStarter/blob/master/src/main/java/oolite/starter/Oolite.java#L781 Still the process (and it's children) needs to be killed explicitly when the user hits the Cancel button.

@k314159 - 1) As I said in my answer: by polling ps -l from a shell and observing the processes that the OS reports ... and their status. 2) Not necessary,  The sleep child process disappeared entirely after 10 seconds ... according to ps -l ... well before the java app exited.  Try it for yourself.  Do you see something different?

@queeg - That is potentially a different effect.  Without looking at that code ... if the child process writes stuff to standard output and the parent doesn't read it all, the Process may need to be explicitly cancelled.  (Need to go to bed.)

@StephenC You run sleep for 10 seconds and have Java wait for 20. Obviously sleep vanishes well before, but that is the child process exiting on it's own. What shall this example demo?

Apologies, I had misunderstood: when I read "are reaped on exit" I thought you meant on exit of the parent process.

@queeg - It is supposed to demonstrate that 1) the child process is reaped, and 2) that it is reaped without the need for a waitFor call ... at least in some circumstances.

A zombie process is one that outlives its creator. You are testing the wrong thing. However provided the Java code calls waitFor() I would find it utterly incredible for a zombie process to be created.
